# show/hide images based on array list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of tags and a list of selected tags:

```
data () {
    return {
        tags: ['#tag1', '#tag2', '#tag3'],
        selectTags: ['#tag1', '#tag2', '#tag3'],
        images: {}
    }
},
```

With them, I created a checkbox loop:

```
<div v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="tag" :value="tag" v-model="selectTags" checked>
    <label :for="tag">{{ tag }}</label>
</div>
```

This tags is used as keys in a list of images. I would like to show/hide image based on `select Tags` list. If this image key in on the list, the image show. Otherwise, it's will be hidden.

```
<template v-for="(tag, index) in images" v-show="selectTags.includes(index)">
    <figure class="thumb" v-for="path in tag['best']['paths']" :key="path">
        <img :src="path | formatImageURL" alt="">
    </figure>
</template>
```

This not works when page loaded and when I uncheck a tag.

Comment: your v-model is set to an array on the checkbox, so if you check that checkbox, selectTags will be set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `v-show` directive on a `template` element, it will have no effect. You need to use it on the child element contained within it, in your case the `figure` element.

See relevant official doc [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show):

> Note that v-show doesn’t support the `<template>` element, nor does it
> work with v-else.